# setstate for checkboxmodal in dialog

Tags: flutter

Here is an example that I used CheckBoxModal to create checkbox list in dialog box,
However, I couldn't get the immediate reflection after I clicked the checkbox button.

Here is the code

```
Container(
      height: 180,
      child: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: false,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          children: [
            Wrap(
              crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
              alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
              children: [
                ...getinstruction
                    .map(
                      (item) => Container(
                        width: 150,
                        child: StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
                          return ListTile(
                            onTap: () {
                              onItemClicked(item);
                            },
                            leading: Checkbox(
                              value: item.value,
                              onChanged: (bool? value) {
                                onItemClicked(item);
                              },
                            ),
                            title: Text(item.title),
                          );
                        }),
                      ),
                    )
                    .toList(),
              ],
            ),
          ]),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `setState` to get it to rebuild

```
onChanged: (bool? value) {
    setState(() => onItemClicked(item));
},
```

However you need to make sure that `item.value` is updated on `onItemClicked`, or within the `onChanged` function.

See [Example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html) from the flutter website on how this is done

Comment: thank you bro, I always forget this 'setstate' function